# Wort für das Fehlverhalten eines Amtsträgers

Tags: single-word-request

Folgende Provinzposse soll sich in Deutschland ereignet haben:

> Ein Betreiber von Windparks beantragte die Genehmigung für ein neues
> Projekt. Zunächst wurde geprüft, ob dort, wo die Anlage entstehen
> sollte, wichtige Vögel leben. Ist dies der Fall, sind Windparks tabu.
> Die Prüfung verlief günstig, ergab nichts, was ein Problem gewesen
> wäre. Dennoch wurde das Projekt abgelehnt. Verwundert ging der
> Betreiber aufs Amt und fragte den zuständigen Sachbearbeiter, ob er
> einen Vogel gefunden hätte. Antwort: »Nein, aber ich habe das
> Bauchgefühl, dass einer da ist.«

Gesucht werden Substantive für das Verhalten des Sachbearbeiters. Ein Substantiv ist dann ein Fund, wenn es folgende Kriterien erfüllt:

- Es ist auf den geschilderten Fall anwendbar
- Es hat einen Bezug zur Staatsdienerschaft des Sachbearbeiters

*Zum Ergebnis*

Als richtige Antwort werte ich (alphabetisch geordnet): Amtsmissbrauch, Behördenwillkür, Ermessensfehlgebrauch, Staatswillkür

Als Antwort ausgewählt habe ich das E-Wort, da ich von seiner Existenz nichts wusste (Lerneffekt).

Comment: Durch die Anekdote wird das Verhalten des Sachbearbeiters nicht hinreichend festgelegt, als daß sich ein Wort dafür finden ließe: *traurig, unverständlich, rätselhaft, irrational, unverschämt, willkürlich, größenwahnsinnig* u.v.a.m. sind mit der Schilderung kompatibel. Die Frage sollte daher überarbeitet werden.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Es wurden doch schon Substantive gefunden, das klappt schon. Bei deinen Adjektiven fehlt der Bezug zur Staatsdienerschaft.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Ich kann dir nur sagen, dass die bisherigen Antwortgeber die Frage so verstanden haben, wie ich sie meine, der Kern der Frage wurde genau getroffen.

Comment: Ich habe die Frage aus dem von David Vogt genannten Grund geschlossen. Sie ist zu vage. Bitte konkretisiere stärker, nach welchem Begriff du suchst.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach: Hilft mein Kommentar von eben?

Comment: Nein. Es geht im Kern darum, dass die Frage auch für künftige Leser:innen Nutzen hat. Zu sagen: "Ich habe eine Frage, auf die _Ermessensfehlgebrauch_ die gewünschte Antwort ist, macht aus einer vagen Fragestellung keine gut gestellte Frage."

Comment: Eine Testfrage ist: Wie sollte jemand, der die gleiche Frage hätte, deine Frage finden? Und: Woher wüsste jemand, der die gleiche Frage hat wie du, dass es die gleiche Frage ist?

Comment: @JonathanScholbach: Eine vage Frage sehe ich nicht, sondern eine präzise, die ebenso beantwortet wurde. Wie viele Personen waren für das Schließen denn nötig?

Comment: @JonathanScholbach was wäre denn deiner Meinung nach eine präzisere Frage, auf die _Ermessensfehlgebrauch_ die Antwort ist? Auf der Schwesternseite _English language_ werden regelmäßig Worte/Ausdrücke gesucht (und gefunden). Ich finde der Titel "Wort für das Fehlverhalten eines Amtsträgers" ist recht treffend und viel wichtiger such- und findbar. Dass du die Frage eigens geschlossen hast finde ich im Bezug auf den Inhalt ein wenig ironisch :)

Comment: Welche Funktion hat denn die Anekdote? Damit soll doch auf eine Art von Fehlverhalten hingedeutet werden. Könnte man vielleicht anstelle der Anekdote eine explizite Beschreibung der Art des Fehlverhaltens setzen? Dieses nicht auszubuchstabieren macht die Frage für mich zum Assoziationsspiel. Wie kann man denn da z.B. gute von schlechten Antworten unterscheiden? (Die Antworten hätten die Frage richtig verstanden, sagt der Fragesteller. Aber wie kann man das nachvollziehen?)

Comment: Ich sehe es genauso wie David Vogt. 

Mögliche Konkretisierungen deiner Frage könnten etwa sein: "Wie bezeichnet man eine willkürliche Entscheidung einer staatlichen Stelle?", oder : "Wie bezeichnet man eine Entscheidung einer staatlichen Stelle, die sachlich unbegründet ist?" oder: "Wie bezeichnet man eine Entscheidung einer staatlichen Stelle, deren Begründung im Widerspruch zu objektiven Fakten steht?" oder "... sachlich falsch ist?". Ich weiß nicht genau, welche es sein soll - das kannst  nur du wissen.

Für das Schließen war nur meine Stimme notwendig, weil ich Moderator bin.

Comment: Zum Test: Ich schätze, dass du "Hohn" nicht als Antwort akzeptieren würdest, oder? Es würde aber auf deine Anekdote passen.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach: »Hohn« passt nicht, da fehlt der staatliche Bezug. Ich habe einen Sachverhalt geschildert und will wissen, welche deutschen Begriffe dafür in Frage kommen. Genau das haben die Antworten geliefert. Ich wurde verstanden. Anscheinend nicht von jedem. Zusatzargument für die Entriegelung der Frage: Wenn jemand einen Begriff aus einer Antwort hat und sucht dafür ein Beispiel, wird er in der Frage fündig.

Comment: Warum sollte es für dafür ein eigenes Wort geben? Manche Sachverhalte bedürfen einer längeren Beschreibung.

Comment: @PaulFrost: Es wurden doch schon Ausdrücke geliefert, es gibt sie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wenn davon ausgegangen wird, dass die Behörde bei ihrer Entscheidung einen Ermessensspielraum hatte, davon aber fehlerhaften Gebrauch gemacht hat, handelt es sich um einen [Ermessensfehlgebrauch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ermessen#Ermessensfehlgebrauch).

Answer (score 3):

Meinst Du "Staatswillkür"?

Dem Antragsteller steht dann der Rechtsweg offen, ich meine es ist eine Dienstaufsichtsbeschwerde, die da in Frage kommt, dann kann man es ein Dienstaufsichtsvergehen nennen.

Comment: Kein Experte (nur Beamtenkind), aber m.W. ist die Dienstaufsichtsbeschwerde (Merksatz: "formlos, fristlos, fruchtlos") nur eine Beschwerde über das Verhalten des Beamten bei deren Vorgesetzten. Gegen die Entscheidung muss man unabhängig davon mit einem Widerspruch und dann ggf. einer Klage vor Gericht vorgehen. Ist aber natürlich alles offtopic hier.

Comment: @HalvarF "Dienstaufsichtsbeschwerde" muss hier hnicht diskutiert werden, denn es war ja nicht die Antwort, sondern "Staatswillkür". Ich unterstelle mal, der zweite Absatz ist nur in der Antwort, weil sie sonst ein bißchen kurz wäre.

Comment: Das ist jetzt nur mein vielleicht relativ willkürliches Bauchgefühl, aber ist es nicht etwas vorschnell, aus dem Verhalten eines einzelnen Sachbearbeiters auf den gesamten Staat zu schließen? Auch wenn es im konkreten Fall so sein mag, dass der Sachbearbeiter an dieser Stelle stellvertretend für den Staat entscheidet, fehlt mir zur vollumfänglichen Staatswillkür irgendwie, dass "der Staat" das willkürliche Verhalten des Sachbearbeiters gutheißt oder auch nur toleriert, nachdem er durch die genannte Dienstaufsichtsbeschwerde darauf aufmerksam gemacht wurde, oder dass diese Willkür ...

Comment: ... zumindest systematisch bei (so gut wie) allen Sachbearbeitern zu beobachten ist.

Comment: @HalvarF: Ja, IANAL, wie der Rechtsweg fachlich genau heißt weiß ich nicht. Vielleicht kommt ja noch ein Jurist und klärt das auf.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Der Begriff "Staatswillkür" muss nicht den ganzen Staat in jeder Entscheidung beschreiben. Deine Interpretation schießt da weit über das Ziel. Ein Akt von Staatswillkür kann auch ein Unikum sein. Es ist auch nicht so, dass bekannt wäre, ob Dienstaufsichtsbeschwerde erhoben wurde. Schon vorher kann das Verhalten sprachlich bewertet werden. Ob sich dem ein Richter anschließt oder nicht wäre eine ganz andere Frage. Jedenfalls handelt der Sachbearbeiter nicht als Kunde, Kumpel, Onkel, Patient, Vorgesetzter etc., sondern als Staatsorgan, daher ist hier von Staatswillkür zu sprechen.

Answer (score 3):

Wie wäre es mit Amts- oder Machtmissbrauch?

Answer (score 0):

Das Geschilderte ist ein Fall von

> Behördenwillkür.

Der Ausdruck hat eine gewisse Verbreitung, im Duden steht er (noch?) nicht.

Bei [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Beh%C3%B6rdenwillk%C3%BCr) ist er gelistet, kurioserweise nicht in der deutschen Version. Offenbar hat sich das Wort bis nach England gefressen.